# Include only CString and CArray into a C++ project

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, mfc, console-application

Say, for my purposes I do not need a full potential of the MFC library. (I'm using it's older version in Visual Studio 2008.) I also need to mention that I compile my projects `statically` against MFC libraries to minimize the number of outside DLL dependencies.

So I think I can get away with using a simple C++ console application project, but there're two classes that I'd like to "borrow" from MFC: `CString` and `CArray`.

Is there any way to include just them in my console application C++ project?

Comment: Why do you want MFC classes? Just use `std::string` and `std::vector` instead

Comment: @Praetorian: Yeah. I know. At this point it's a matter or preference, or previous experience.

Comment: @ahmd0: IIRC, `CArray` is buggy anyways.

Comment: @MooingDuck: Just curious, what is buggy about `CArray`?

Comment: You may want to use this CString clone:http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1146/CString-clone-Using-Standard-C When I still programmed in MFC I used this in projects similar to your need.

Comment: @ahmd0: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4h2f09ct(v=vs.90).aspx "Most methods that resize a CArray object or add elements to it use memcpy_s to move elements. This is a problem because memcpy_s is not compatible with any objects that require the constructor to be called. If the items in the CArray are not compatible with memcpy_s, you must create a new CArray of the appropriate size. You must then use CArray::Copy and CArray::SetAt to populate the new array because those methods use an assignment operator instead of memcpy_s."

Comment: @MooingDuck: Oh yeah. I'm aware of that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best is to leave those out of your projects (I tried since I liked the CString class). Most methods of CString can be replaced by std::string and std::stringstream.

Comment: Take Adam Galarneau's excellent advice: **DON'T USE MFC IF YOU CAN AVOID IT!**  MFC is obsolete; you should really use contemporary APIs and libraries for any new code.  IMHO...

Comment: Thanks. As I said above, I have a lot of experience with MFC and to learn new stuff on such a fundamental level will slow me down a big time.

Comment: Does Microsoft provide `std::string` and `std::vector`? What do I need to include?

Comment: #incldue <string> and #include <vector>, but I think Adam should now get more rep because it is not 666. ;-)

Comment: Tks for not leaving me at 666. =P

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your exact use case, you can also use [QString](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/qt5-stable/qtcore/qstringhtml) and [QByteArray](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/qt5-stable/qtcore/qbytearray.html) if you needed more then stl. You would only need to link against the qtcore dll, and it will leave flexibility to use the same code later on other platforms compared to MFC. Although that would be true with STL, too.

Comment: Hmm, I wonder why an alternative solution got -1? Care to elaborate?

Comment: " I do not need a full potential of the MFC library".  If a couple MFC headers that is already installed is overkill, odds are installing QT is serious overkill as well.

Comment: But Qt has two advantages over MFC: 1) it's cross-platform, 2) it's not obsolete (yes...).  Of course, if the issue is "arrays" and "string" in C++, arguably the *only* reasonable answer is "use the C++ standard library".  IMHO...

Comment: @paulsm4: yes, and I even wrote my answer conditionally. Mooing did not bother to understand fully.

Answer (score 1):

MFC is not needed to use CString.

The current version of CString is available if you #include "atlstr.h"

Comment: Yes, I know. But what about `CArray`?